# Visual Studio XML summaries not working

Tags: visual-studio-2015, comments, xml-comments

When I used to use Visual Studio I could use /// to declare a summary of my method at the and it would autogenerate all the tags and add a line for any params however after installing Visual Studio 2015 I no longer seem able to do this by default. Is there something I need to enable in the settings? I'm coding in C++ however if I don't think that is the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is a Visual Studio setting. For C#, you turn it on by going to `Tools -> Options` and ensuring that the *Generate XML documentation comments for ///* is enabled.

[image]

There is a similar setting under Basic for VB, but I can't see a similar setting for C++ (I don't have the full C++ feature installed though so that may be why). Hopefully you can find a similar setting.

Comment: Ahh thanks, so that option is there for C# but unfortunately not for C++. Maybe it's an exclusive C# option. Thank you though

Comment: @AntonioGravano [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4059879/116923) suggests that C++ doesn't support it, but there is an extension that can add the behaviour.

Comment: In my VS Version 16.9.5 it does not work at all :P

Answer (score 1):

I got this too, and furthermore none of my short-cut keys worked any longer!

Turns out I was in folder-view, instead of solution-view... DOH

Answer (score 0):

Just an update to Visual Studio 2022:
[image]