# /// not creating summaries for methods and functions

Tags: c#, xml, intellisense, visual-studio-2019

Usually in visual studio adding /// before a type or type member generates a summary. However, when I try using /// it only completes namespaces, classes and entry points not methods or functions. This issue only occurs in recently created solutions with older ones behaving as expected.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Generates summary for entry point
        /// </summary>
        static void Main()
        {
           /// Doesn't generate summary.
           void ExampleVoid() {
...
```

I have recently adjusted some Intellisense options however, I haven't found any options that would have caused this.

[Generate XML documentation comments for /// is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41005000/11522147)

Edit:
I've also noticed that intellisense descriptions aren't showing for [methods or system classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37500027/11522147), adjusting statement completion isn't fixing this. [Reinstalling the framework may be the solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37591972/11522147)

[Example of description not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nT5lM.png)

Comment: The code was meant to illustrate what /// auto generated and what it did not. In this case /// autogenerated for the entry point  creating the <summary> </summary>.  /// didnt autogenerate a summary for void ExampleVoid(). If I were to do this in a older solution /// would have auto generated a summary with an opening and closing statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `Main` being an entry method.

Local functions can't have doc-comments.  It's the same reason you can't doc-comment variables in a method, but you can doc-comment properties.

You are trying to declare the method `ExampleVoid` inside `Main`.  If you want to write a doc-comment for this method, make it a top-level method like `Main`, and make it static so it can be called from a static method:

```
static void Main()
{
    ExampleVoid();
}

static void ExampleVoid() 
{
}
```