# How to make Visual Studio 2022 documentation generation?

Tags: c++, documentation-generation

I'm trying to generate documentation in **c++ project (VS 2022 Community)** using xml-tags in comments like **<summary>**, **<returns>** and so on. I was searching project setting, configured output file and rebuild project. But result was zero. I can't find output file. Was it generated at all? Can't understand where he is. I know there are also several programs/plug-ins making doc, but I want to try embeed services. Output file setting is **$(OutDir)$(TargetName).xml**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059773/generate-xml-documentation-comments-for-in-visual-studio-2010-c

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED! =)
So, to generate documentaion you need to enable option **Create XML-documentaion file** at **Project->Settings->C/C++**
Default setting of files path are working. Another options are in **Project->Settings->XML-documentation generation**
Ah... It was difficult to find. No link in official docs to this theme)

Comment: Thank you. I had to disable this setting. In VS2022 the option is found under **Project->Properties->C/C++->Output Files->Generate XML Documentation Files**

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .csproj file

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```